# using table with store table names and column names for comparison in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, comparison

I have a table with columns `old_table`, `new_table`, `old_column` and `new_column`. i have inserted into these table names as well as corresponding column names from within the database to use for a comparison. This way I can do all the comparison from the new to the old table column within one table.

My problem is I don't really know how to go about this. I was thinking of dynamic SQL or fetching and looping through each row but not really sure. I need to be able to call the first row of the table which will have one of each of these columns (`old_table`, `new_table`, `old_column` and `new_column`) and be able to use the two column names in a select statement , then use the two table names in the FROM clause. And then so on for each row within the table.

Any help on an approach would be much appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the information you need from the system tables?

Comment: first of  all, we don't know what you do with your tables and when. Do you have dynamic table creation logic in your application and keeping track of tables created and deleted? At this point, it is unclear what you asking. If you want information about existing tables/columns, you have user_tables, etc for it.

Comment: It'd be a pretty interesting join...You would need to take a list of the columns required by the script you are creating (and table names I guess), then join to this table here...then loop a query that builds a var for dynamic execution.  Dan's idea is likely better, just read sysobjects to get the current state, however that would not handle old table name vs new table name very well.  Honestly, to need the 'old table name / new table name' setup, you have people using a database pretty poorly...table names shouldn't change.  What business requirement are you trying to meet here?

Comment: Can you clarify the end result you are looking for?  Are you wanting a count of how many rows are different for each column (so you would need a query for each row in your table)?  Or do you just need to know what is different between the old and new tables (so a query for each distinct new/old table combination)?

Comment: si ive already done this using queries doing the regular tables. im doing this so its a type of metadata approach want i want to do is for example                                                          select column_name_old,column_name_new                             from old_table,New_table                                                                                                                                                         but in reality i want it to insert the row from the table of all the lists so example old_table would be replaced by id,and new table id2 then so on

Comment: for the tables. so pretty much its using variables as column titles in the meta data table and plugging in the first row records into the corresponding spots within a select statement                                       select column_name_old(want it to be id),column_name_new(id2)         from old_table(table1 within first row of metadata table),new_table_in(table2)                                                                    im doing this because it's another way to deal with massive and i mean massive amounts of two table comparisons i need to do.